# Checking if a request array is empty in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a dynamically generated form that gives me an array of inputs. However the array might be empty, then the foreach will fail.

```
    public function myfunction(Request $request)
    {
    if(isset($request))
     {
       #do something
     }

    }
```

This obviously doesn't work since it is a $request object and is always set. I have no idea however how to check if there is any input at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always do this with my installations by adding a function to the `Controller` in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function hasInput(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('_token')) {
        return count($request->all()) > 1;
    } else {
        return count($request->all()) > 0;
    }
}
```

Rather self explanatory, return true if other input variables outside of the `_token`, or return true if no `token` and contains other variables.

Comment: You could simplify this function by getting rid of those inner `if` statements and instead using `return count($request->all()) > 0;` or `return count($request->all()) > 1;`

Comment: ^ exactly. No need for the else. The first if statement will return true or false.

Answer (score 12):

A simple count check will do

```
if (count($request->all())) {
  // foreach here.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Request class has a `except()` method that includes everything except the key/keys defined. So:

```
if ( !empty( $request->except('_token') ) )
```

execute the code when there is "something" in the request array.

Comment: I would go for this 

if (!empty($request->except('_token','_method')))

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reference of the form inputs you're expecting, then `Request::has()` might be a good method to use. `Request::all()` could contain things like the XSRF token and would give you false positives.

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification @Saravanan code above. I agree with him that a simple check on the total number of inputs in the request will do.

```
if(count($request->all()) >= 1)
{
   //execute if the request has one or more input fields
}
else {
  //executes if the request is totally empty.
}
```