# PHP not receiving POST array when it is sent empty from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel. When I `dd($request->all())` it prints data only when the array is not empty i.e. `Array['some-value']`. When I `console.log(data)` in jQuery, it logs in console that it is an array but just doesn't have any value inside. However in Laravel I can't get that empty array, but I can get it when it has value. I want to send array even if it's empty.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <!-- It sends but doesn't show in Laravel when this active class below is not exists -->
    <li class="active" data-motion="1">motion 1</li>
    <li data-motion="2">motion 2</li>
    <li data-motion="3">motion 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$.each($('ul li.active'), function(index, motion) {
    motion = $(motion).attr('data-motion');
    params['motions'].push(motion);
});

// it shows the empty array when that active class is not there,
// which is the one I want to get in Laravel too.
consol.log(params);

$.ajax({
    url: '/my-motions',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,
    success: function(response) {
        params = [];
    },
    error: function(error) {
        //
    }
});
```

Laravel:

```
public function myFunc(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    dd($data);
    // The result: nothing
    // What I want: array:0 [] 
}
```

Comment: Show your relevant code, both PHP and JS.

Comment: Just check if the request is empty in if condition. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230304/checking-if-a-request-array-is-empty-in-laravel

Comment: What's the output of `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: the output is `[]` but i have lots of other key/value pairs. the result when not sending the param is `[['some-key' => 'some-value'], ['some-key2' => 'some-value2'], ['motions' => ['1','2','3']]]` and what I want is `[['some-key' => 'some-value'], ['some-key2' => 'some-value2'], ['motions' => []]]`

Comment: try passing `data:{motion:motionArr}`

Comment: Have you tried `motion = $(motion).attr('data-motion') || '';`

Comment: As I said when I `console.log(params)` it returns an empty array and it's working correctly but when I print it in Laravel it is not even SET!